# XML to array - Group Array results based on one child element

Tags: php, arrays, grouping, sorting

I have a XML which I converted to array without a problem, the original XML looks something like this.

```
<somedata>data</somedata>
<somedata2>data2</somedata2>
<level1>
   <listings>
     <element>
        <title>AAA</title>
        <description>DescriptionA</description>
        <moredata>
          <adate>2012/12/12</adate>
        </moredata>
     </element>

     <element>
        <title>AAA</title>
        <description>DescriptionA</description>
        <moredata>
          <adate>2013/10/12</adate>
        </moredata>
     </element>

     <element>
        <title>BBB</title>
        <description>DescriptionB</description>
        <moredata>
          <adate>2012/09/01</adate>
        </moredata>
     </element>
   </listings>
<level1>
```

Of course so far everything looks fine, I get my nice array with all the child objects, but I need to create an HTML output by grouping the elements by for example the Title, considering that my Output would look something like this.

```
Title: AAA
Description: DescriptionA
Date 1: 2012/12/12
Date 2: 2013/10/12

Title: BBB
Description: DescriptionB
Date 1: 2012/09/01
```

Notice I have grouped AAA which was repeated and listed both dates within the same result.

How in PHP, I was seriously thinking on saving to mysql then pulling them back, but that will simply be a bad patch.

Hope anyone can help.

Regards

Comment: Are you able to restructure your source XML document? that would be more logical and save bytes.

Answer (score 2):

this is a rough concept how i'd do it.

you have to parse the xml with [simplexml](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php) into an array, after that you can customize your html output.

```
$result = array();

foreach($xml->element as $element){

   $line = array();
   $line['date'] = $element->date;
   $line['description'] = $element->description;

   $result[$element->title]['line'][] = $line;

}
```

Comment: I kind of understand your code, perhaps I cant implement it, need something more precise for the depth and example above, the sorting factor is the name in this case. 4 to 5 levels. THANKS!!!!!

Comment: I already have an array out of the XML, I am stuck on the process of grouping each LISTING on a unique list with the dates inside combines as the example above.

Comment: do you want to walk through $xml->somedata->level1. be more specific

Comment: somedata we dont need it, everything starts from "listings", for each "element" found, create the array, but those repeated I want to create an array of dates, instead of having the same "element" twise, only once but with an array of dates which came from all the listings found with the same name.